# Por que mongol significa idiota/estúpido?

Tags: etimologia, gíria, semântica

É comum em linguagem casual ouvir o termo mongol ou mongoloide para designar um indivíduo que tenha (ou aja como) capacidades cognitivas limitadas. Pode-se dizer que o termo já se consagrou no registro popular com esse significado.

Todavia, o Priberam e outros dicionários apenas incluem este verbete exclusivamente:

> mon·gol
>
> adjetivo de dois gêneros
>
> 1. Relativo à Mongólia ou aos mongóis. = MONGÓLICO
>
> substantivo de dois gêneros
>
> 2. Natural, habitante ou cidadão da Mongólia.
>
> substantivo masculino
>
> 3. [Linguística]  Língua dos mongóis.

Como o vocábulo passou de uma nacionalidade à pejoratividade?

Comment: Acredito que é apenas mais uma daquelas expressões pejorativas que não deviam existir. Relacionar a doença Síndrome de Down a um povo inteiro é muito mau mesmo, é como as inúmeras expressões pejorativas contra o que é negro: denegrir, magia negra, etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Portadores da Síndrome de Down — os quais estão, em muitos casos, cognitivamente em desvantagem em relação a um indivíduo geneticamente típico — foram associados e comparados à etnia mongol no decorrer da ciência do século XIX.

Por intermédio de convenção científica e publicações do mesmo teor, o termo mongol se popularizou para nomear aqueles que possuíam a trissomia do cromossomo 21, consequentemente sendo também utilizado para denominar aqueles que, mesmo normais, apresentavam desabilidades mentais.

Portanto, sendo um termo ofensivo a alguém 'normal' ser comparado a alguém de atributos inferiores, a palavra 'mongol' começou a ser utilizada como insulto para acusar alguém de idiotice/estupidez.

TL;DR:

Em seus estudos da trissomia 21 (Síndrome de Down), John Langdon Down descreveu que `'um grande número de idiotas congénitos são Mongois [referente à etnia mongol] típicos'`, aludindo às características físicas de um portador da síndrome e de um pertencente à etnia mongol — que são de fato similares. Também comentou que a raça mongol deveria ser inferior às demais.

Seu filho, Reginald Down, avançou no tema ao propor que a síndrome de Down na verdade era uma etapa além da etnia mongol no que concerne à degenerância humana (muitos etnologistas da época inclusive acreditavam que a espécie humana se originava dos mongois, supostamente os mais primitivos).

Francis Graham Crookshank alega em seu livro, The Mongol in Our Midst, que a `'imbecilidade mongoloide'`, como chamava, era um atavismo retrógrado para a raça mongol, novamente, considerada primitiva. Como argumentos da sua tese, Crookshank apresentou exemplos das características físicas e comportamentais supostamente compartilhadas entre os 'imbecis' e o povo mongol. No início do século XX, “mongolismo” se difundiu como descritivo para a síndrome de Down.

Apenas em 1959, quando um médico geneticista descobriu uma unidade extra no cromossomo 21 no cariótipo dos portadores de Down, que o termo 'mongoloide' para a doença passou a ser criticado por intelectuais e pelo próprio país Mongólia; em 1965, a expressão 'síndrome de Down' foi oficializada pela Organização Mundial de Saúde.

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma coisa chamada "pirâmide de eufemismos" - uma palavra que era usada para evitar um xingamento acaba sendo usada como xingamento - isso ocorre frequentemente nas doenças mentais.

Então temos "mongoloide" usado como termo neutro, mas depois de um tempo vira "idiota", depois usamos "retardado" como termo neutro, para mostrar que a pessoa tem um atrasado mental, e ela também para de ser neutra. Passamos para deficiente físico e mental, mas depois ninguém quer ser deficiente e passamos para eficiente, etc, depois de um tempo todas as palavras neutras acabam virando em si palavras feias, porque a palavra apenas reflete o tabu da sociedade.